# ¿Cómo crear una variable índice en R?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Estoy intentando replicar un índice en función de ciertas variables que aquí se pueden visualizar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por esto que cree un data frame con las variables que utiliza para codificar, que se puede ver en mi repositorio. El archivo se llama "ranking": https://github.com/florenciagayraud/usaidpry

Ahora bien, me gustaría (para poder luego graficar este ranking) tener una variable que sea el valor final de la sumatoria de todas estas variables codificadas tal como indica. Para esto pensé primero en generar un código que codifique 1 o 0 en función de lo que el cuadro plantea, y salvo el caso de las variables "supnom" y "supap" pareciera funcionar:

```
ranking <- usaid_pry2 %>% 
  select(country, year, judind, supterm, supnom_1, supnom_2, supnom_3, supnom_4, supnom_5, supnom_6, supnom_7,
         supap_1, supap_2, supap_3, supap_4, supap_5, supap_6, supap_7, jrem, jrempro_4, jrempro_5, jrempro_6,
         jrempro_8, jrempro_9, jremap_1, jremap_2, jremap_3, jremap_4, jremap_5, jremap_6, jremap_7, jremap_96,
         jremcon_1, jremcon_2, jremcon_3, jremcon_4, jremcon_5, jremcon_90, judsal) %>% 
  mutate(judind = case_when(judind == 1 ~ 1, is.na(judind) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         supterm = case_when(supterm %in% 88:89 ~ 1, is.na(supterm) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         sup_norm_ap = case_when((supnom_6 | supnom_7) == 1 ~ 1,
                                 (supnom_1 | supnom_2 | supnom_3) == 1 & (supap_4 | supap_5 | supap_6 | supap_7) == 1 ~ 1,
                                 (supnom_4 | supnom_5) == 1 & (supap_1 | supap_2 | supap_3 | supap_6 | supap_7) == 1 ~ 1,
                                 is.na(supap_1) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jrem = case_when(jrem == 2 ~ 1, is.na(jrem) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jrempro = case_when((jrempro_8 | jrempro_9) == 1 ~ 1, is.na(jrempro_8) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jremap = case_when((jrempro_4 | jrempro_5 | jrempro_6) != 1 & (jremap_1 | jremap_2 | jremap_3 | jremap_4 | jremap_5 | jremap_6 | jremap_7 | jremap_96) == 1 ~ 1,
                            is.na(jrempro_5) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jremcon = case_when(jremcon_2 | jremcon_3 | jremcon_4 | jremcon_5 == 1 ~ 1,
                             is.na(jremcon_2) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         judsal = case_when(judsal == 1 ~ 1, is.na(judsal) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0))
```

Probablemente esté utilizando mal la lógica del case_when o quizás hay otra forma de hacerlo. Pensé en quizás utilizar todas las combinaciones de variables pero suena bastante engorroso. Asimismo, desagregué en tres partes (jrem, jrempro y jremap) lo que debería ser una sola variable.

Por otro lado, una vez logrado esto pensé en seleccionar las variables creadas junto con país y año, pero luego me gustaría poder sumar en otra variable adicional el valor que obtiene cada país en cada año y no sabría como hacerlo. Intuyo que con apply podría lograrlo. Es decir, el ranking o el índice sería una sumatoria de los valores de estas seis variables nuevas para cada caso y cada año, de modo que tomaría valores entre 0 y 6. Y sería esta variable la que desearía graficar. 
Espero haber sido clara y gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo haberlo solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
ranking <- usaid_pry2 %>% 
  select(country, year, judind, supterm, supnom_1, supnom_2, supnom_3, supnom_4, supnom_5, supnom_6, supnom_7,
         supap_1, supap_2, supap_3, supap_4, supap_5, supap_6, supap_7, jrem, jrempro_4, jrempro_5, jrempro_6,
         jrempro_8, jrempro_9, jremap_1, jremap_2, jremap_3, jremap_4, jremap_5, jremap_6, jremap_7, jremap_96,
         jremcon_1, jremcon_2, jremcon_3, jremcon_4, jremcon_5, jremcon_90, judsal) %>% 
  mutate(judind = case_when(judind == 1 ~ 1, is.na(judind) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         supterm = case_when(supterm %in% 88:89 ~ 1, is.na(supterm) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         sup_nom_ap = case_when(supnom_6 == 1 ~ 1, supnom_7 == 1 ~ 1, supnom_6 > 1 ~ 0, 
                                (supnom_1 | supnom_2 | supnom_3) == 1 & (supap_4 | supap_5 | supap_6 | supap_7) == 1 ~ 1,
                                (supnom_4 | supnom_5) == 1 & (supap_1 | supap_2 | supap_3 | supap_6 | supap_7) == 1 ~ 1,
                                is.na(supnom_6) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jrem_pro_map = case_when(jrem == 2 ~ 1, jrempro_8 == 1 ~ 1, jrempro_9 == 1 ~ 1, 
                                  (jrempro_4 | jrempro_5 | jrempro_6) != 1 & (jremap_1 | jremap_2 | jremap_3 | jremap_4 | jremap_5 | jremap_6 | jremap_7 | jremap_96) == 1 ~ 1,
                                  is.na(jrem) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         jremcon = case_when(jremcon_2 == 1 ~ 1, jremcon_3 == 1 ~ 1, jremcon_4 == 1 ~ 1, jremcon_5 == 1 ~ 1,
                             jremcon_2 > 1 ~ 0, is.na(jremcon_2) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0),
         judsal = case_when(judsal == 1 ~ 1, is.na(judsal) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  select(country, year, judind, supterm, sup_nom_ap, jrem_pro_map, jremcon, judsal) %>% 
  mutate(ocde = ifelse(country %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", 
                                      "Chile", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", 
                                      "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
                                      "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", 
                                      "Italy", "Japan", "South Korea", 
                                      "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
                                      "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", 
                                      "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", 
                                      "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", 
                                      "United Kingdom", "United States of America"), 1, 0), 
         latam = ifelse(country %in% c("Uruguay", "Costa Rica", "Chile", "Argentina",
                                       "Panama", "Brazil", "Paraguay"), 1, 0),
         "upper-middle" = ifelse(country %in% c("Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa",
                                                "Argentina", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", 
                                                "Belarus", "Belize", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana",
                                                "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "China", "Colombia", "Costa Rica",
                                                "Cuba", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador",
                                                "Equatorial Guinea", "Fiji", "Gabon", "Georgia",
                                                "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guyana", "Iran", "Iraq", 
                                                "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Kazahstan", "Kosovo",
                                                "Lebanon", "Libya", "Malaysia", "Maldives", 
                                                "Marshall Islands", "Mauritius", "Mexico",
                                                "Montenegro", "Namibia","Nauru", 
                                                "North Macedonia", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Romania", 
                                                "Russia", "Samoa", "Serbia", 
                                                "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "St. Lucia", 
                                                "St. Vincent and the Grenadines",
                                                "Suriname", "Thailand", "Tonga",
                                                "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu","Venezuela"), 1, 0))


ranking$index <- rowSums(ranking[ ,3:8])


dataParaguay_ccpcnc <- ranking %>% filter(country == "Paraguay") %>% select(country, year, index) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(index)) %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(mean_pry_year=mean(index))

dataocde_ccpcnc <- ranking %>% filter(ocde == 1) %>% select(country, year, index) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(index)) %>% group_by(year) %>%  
  summarise(mean_ocde_year=mean(index))

datalatam_ccpcnc <- ranking %>% filter(latam == 1) %>% select(country, year, index) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(index)) %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_latam_year=mean(index))

datauppermid_ccpcnc <- ranking %>% filter(`upper-middle` == 1) %>% 
  select(country, year, index) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(index)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_uppermid_year=mean(index)) 

ggplot() + geom_point(dataParaguay_ccpcnc, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_pry_year, color = "Paraguay")) +
  geom_point(data = dataocde_ccpcnc, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_ocde_year, color = "OCDE")) + 
  geom_point(data = datauppermid_ccpcnc, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_uppermid_year, color = "upper-middle")) + 
  geom_point(data = datalatam_ccpcnc, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_latam_year, color = "Latam")) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1789", "1819", "1849", "1879", "1909", "1939", "1969", "1999", "2013")) +
  labs(x = "años", y = "Índice de Independencia Judicial (CCPCNC)") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,6), expand = c(0,0) )
```

Probablemente haya formas más eficientes de hacerlo, pero parece funcionar bien!

Comment: No olvides considerar que si fue la solución la puedes marcar como aceptada